# Is there a way to download Photoshop without Creative Cloud?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to use Photoshop and my trial key became invalid yesterday. I want to download Photoshop but I can only see plans with this cloud stuff, 'Creative Cloud' where the cheapest version is $19/mo.

I want Photoshop without this cloud and without monthly fees. In my opinion this is completely useless. Or at least for me. I just want to pay a one-time fee, download it and use it.

Is this still possible? Via chat someone told me that CS with a one-time fee is no longer possible, but that only CC is available now with monthly fees. I'd like confirmation.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Comment: I'm not sure what more of an answer we can give you, you got an employee of the company to tell you that an outright purchase of their product is no longer available. This is also off-topic due to the shopping advice nature of the question.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Which employee?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had mentioned talking with an employee over chat. My mind must've been making stuff up.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Oh. Doesn't matter ;) I understand that you could've made this mistake, it wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 1):

As of posting this answer you can still buy the Creative Suite 6 products as a Collection or Individually [here](http://www.adobe.com/products/catalog/cs6._sl_id-contentfilter_sl_catalog_sl_software_sl_creativesuite6.html).

**NOTE**: The above link may stop working at any point in time.